# NullPointerException in CMUSphinx

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, cmusphinx

I have written a small program to generate SRT files for a given Audio using CMUSphinx. The program worked fine for all but one audio, where I am getting a NullPointerException, after two of the hypothesis get done. Appending the program:

```
package sphinxtest;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import edu.cmu.sphinx.alignment.LongTextAligner;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Configuration;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechAligner;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.StreamSpeechRecognizer;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.adaptation.Stats;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.adaptation.Transform;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.result.WordResult;


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Loading models...");

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

    // Load model from the jar
    configuration
            .setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");

    configuration
            .setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");
    configuration
            .setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin");

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter File name");
    String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
    String filename_sans_extension = filename.substring(0, filename.length()-4);

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(filename_sans_extension+".srt", "UTF-8");

    StreamSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new StreamSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
    recognizer.startRecognition(new FileInputStream("data\\"+filename));       
    SpeechResult result; 
    int line_number=1;
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null) {
        int numOfWords = result.getWords().size();
        writer.println(line_number);
        writer.println(func2(result.getWords().get(0).getTimeFrame().getStart()) + " --> " +
        func2(result.getWords().get(numOfWords-1).getTimeFrame().getEnd()) );
        writer.println(result.getHypothesis());
        writer.println();
        line_number++;
    }
   writer.close();

   long endTime = System.nanoTime();
   System.out.println("Took "+(endTime - startTime) + " ns");
}

private static String func2(long n) {
    return func1(n / 3600000000l, 2) + ":" + func1(n / 60000000 % 60, 2) + ":" 
            + func1(n / 1000000 % 60, 2) + "," + func1(n / 1000 % 1000, 3);
}

private static String func1(long n, int i) {
    String s = String.valueOf(n);
    while (s.length() < i) {
        s = "0" + s;
    }
    return s;
}
```

}

The exception looks like this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at edu.cmu.sphinx.result.Lattice.(Lattice.java:171)
>       at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult.(SpeechResult.java:38)
>       at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.AbstractSpeechRecognizer.getResult(AbstractSpeechRecognizer.java:61)
>       at sphinxtest.Main.main(Main.java:54)

Line 54 is the while statement in the code.

Any help here? I am unable to figure what exactly is wrong with the particular audio it is not working with. All my audio files are basically the audio files from Ted talks which I have converted into a format that works best for Sphinx using FFMPEG.

---

EDIT: Adding more information based on the comments.

I am using the audio from the following video: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UF8uR6Z6KLc

A link to exact wav file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2RCuY-PDtQ8dTNIb0ZtN2t3S3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to share that particular audio to get help on this issue

Comment: It is better if you share the wav file, not the video link

Comment: I have added the particular audio as well. Another point to add is that my problem was eventually resolved when I used the latest Acoustic and Language model files that I downloaded from the website, instead of the ones shipped with the Jar files.